# file_exists() or is_dir not working

Tags: php, file-exists

I want to check if the path exists, I have tried:

```
if(is_dir('/public_html/uploads/2013/')){
    //do stuff
} else {
    //do stuff
}
```

Also tried

```
var_dump(is_dir('/public_html/uploads/2013/'));
```

Returns false, but the path exists.

I also tried:

```
if(file_exists('/public_html/uploads/2013/')){
    //do stuff
} else {
    //do stuff
}
```

No luck, any ideas? I'm all out.

Comment: Change the path to an absolute one. Something like `/var/www/some_site/public_html/uploads/2013`.

Comment: Are you sure /public_html/ exist?  Try echo __FILE__; and see the full path

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that path `/public_html/uploads/2013` exists at your system, because it is not a relative, but an absoulte path from the root of the filesystem, because of the starting `/`.

Comment: Correct, I thought I would try an absolute path and this worked :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`/public_html/` suggests that the folder `public_html` is in the root of your system, which is probably not the case. Make the path relative, or use a full absolute path. You can use constants like `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` [Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to find out where in the file system your script is.